# How do i add space(margin-bottom ) between the li's of my ul?

Tags: css

Hi i am trying to add some space below each li of my ul. When i try to set margin-bottom on the li it does not work it just adds margin above the first li element of the list. Can someone tell me how i can add a space(margin) bellow each li

Comment: please show us the html and css

Comment: @vijar:Please make a fiddle for your problem. Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/qY9f5/

Comment: looks like a general margin collapse problem, i assume you have the ul inside a container, if you assign some minor padding to either top or bottom of it (container {padding:0 0 1px;}) it would solve the issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
ul li{margin-bottom:10px;}
```

You can check the example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gdfxk/

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried that:

http://jsfiddle.net/UV99e/2/

And it seems to work.

Html :

```
<ul class="ul1">
    <li>Toto</li>
    <li>Titi</li>
    <li>Tata</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul2">
    <li>Toto</li>
    <li>Titi</li>
    <li>Tata</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul3">
    <li>Toto</li>
    <li>Titi</li>
    <li>Tata</li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
li
{    
    background-color : gray;
    height : 25px;
}

.ul1>li
{
    margin-bottom : 0px;
}

.ul2>li
{
    margin-bottom : 5px;
}

.ul3>li
{
    margin-bottom : 5px;
}
```